# Can we change Default time provide by spring in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: date, datetime, spring-mvc, spring-data, simpledateformat

```
    this.mdbReading.y = new Date[reading.y.length];
    SimpleDateFormat ydateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    
    for ( i = 0; i < reading.y.length; i++) {    
        //System.out.println("i = " + i + " string is "+ reading.y[i]);                                   
        try {
            
            this.mdbReading.y[i] = ydateFormat.parse(reading.y[i]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Exception in date parse "+ e);
            break;
        }
    }
```

This is my code,where input string i.e `reading.y[i]` is in this format "2016-04-28" ..I am getting output  as "2016-04-24 T18.30:00 00:00:00" while I am expecting output as "2016-04-24 T00.000:00 00:00:00" ..so is there any way to set the default time to 00:00?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See the answer.

Comment: [Anti-pattern: parallel collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/). You haven’t posted complete code, so it’s hard to be sure. I think I smell a poor design. If so, the link should help.

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2016-04-28");
        System.out.println(date);

        // In case you also need time-part as 00:00
        LocalDateTime ldt = date.atTime(LocalTime.MIN);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2016-04-28
2016-04-28T00:00
```

The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards. Your date string is already in the ISO 8601 format.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

#### What went wrong with your code?

By default `SimpleDateFormat` uses the default timezone while parsing any string. Given below is the code to reproduce your error:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        System.out.println(sdf.parse("2016-04-28").toInstant());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2016-04-27T18:30:00Z
```

In order to keep the time part `00:00:00`, you need to set UTC timezone to the `SimpleDateFormat` instance.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        System.out.println(sdf.parse("2016-04-28").toInstant());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2016-04-28T00:00:00Z
```

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>