# Javax Rest API dateformat on result JSON

Tags: java, spring, date, timezone, date-format

Initially, the SpringFramework WAR application was deployed in a Server in which date format in JSON Result `Oct 27, 2021 11:23:48 AM` even in my local the same.

But the same application is deployed into a new server, now the date format in the result is quite different `Oct 27, 2021, 3:38:02 PM`
Extra comma has been added after the year.

the old server is **EST** timezone, now the new server is **UTC** timezone.  Without changing time zone What should I do at the code level?

What is the issue? how can I have the same date format as in Old Server?

Comment: I guess that depends on the underlying system running the server.

Comment: yes I know, the old server is EST timezone, now the new server is UTC timezone.  Without changing time zone What should I do at the code level?

Comment: Which Java class are you using for date?

Comment: Date from util package

Answer (score 0):

Try with ZonedDateTime.

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String formattedString = zonedDateTime.format(formatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the issue?

A `java.util.Date` object simply represents an instant on the timeline — a wrapper around the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT). Since it does not hold any `Timezone` and `Locale` information, its **[`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--)** function applies the JVM's `Timezone` and `Locale` to return a `String` in the format, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`, derived from this ***milliseconds*** value. To get the `String` representation of the `java.util.Date` object in a different format, `Timezone` and `Locale`, you need to use `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired format and the applicable `Timezone` and `Locale` e.g.

```
Date date = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
String strDateNewYork = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(strDateNewYork);

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
String strDateUtc = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(strDateUtc);
```

So you see different representations of the same instant i.e.

**Oct 27, 2021 11:23:48 AM at America/New_York = Oct 27, 2021, 3:38:02 PM at UTC**

because your server is applying the server's timezone by default. If you want the values to be always in a fixed `Timezone`, specify the same explicitly as shown above.

> how can I have the same date format as in Old Server?

If you want the values to be always in a fixed `Locale`, specify the same explicitly as shown above.

#### Switch to `java.time`:

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

You can use `java.time.Instant` whose [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) method uses ISO-8601 representation and therefore the output remains the same irrespective of the timezone setting of the server.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        System.out.println(now);
    }
}
```

If you want to display this instant in different timezones, you can obtain the respective `ZonedDateTime` by using [`Instant.atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        System.out.println(now);

        ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(zdtNewYork);

        ZonedDateTime zdtIndia = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
        System.out.println(zdtIndia);
    }
}
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>