# How to use java.time.ZonedDateTime & format.DateTimeFormatter without GMT?

Tags: java, java-time

Doing the following:

```
val zonedFormatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm z")

ZonedDateTime.from(zonedFormatter.parse("31.07.2020 14:15 GMT"))
```

Gives me:

```
"displayDate": "2020-07-31T14:15:00Z[GMT]"
```

I want it without the [GMT]:

```
"displayDate": "2020-07-31T14:15:00Z"
```

Comment: _Gives me_ What "gives you"? Is this JSON? Are you serializing an instance containing a `ZonedDateTime` somewhere? How?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) to format the parsed `ZonedDateTime`. However, if you are expecting the date-time always in UTC, I recommend you convert the parsed `ZonedDateTime` into `Instant`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm z", Locale.ENGLISH);

        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.from(dtfInput.parse("31.07.2020 14:15 GMT"));
        System.out.println(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));

        System.out.println(zdt.toInstant());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-07-31T14:15:00Z
2020-07-31T14:15:00Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/9qbyaF)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>