# Kotlin/java - How to convert a date time string to Instant?

Tags: java, kotlin, zoneddatetime

I am trying to create an instance of Instant from date and time strings. Date is formatted like this `yyyy-MM-dd`. So the values could look like this:

```
val date = "2021-11-25"
val time = "15:20"
```

I am trying to make a valid instant from this 2 strings like this:

```
val dateTime = "${date}T${time}:00"
val instantDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTime, 
                                          DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.withZone(defaultTimeZone)
                                         ).toInstant()
```

I have also tried with it:

```
val instantDateTime = Instant.from(DateTimeFormatter .ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.withZone(defaultTimeZone).parse(dateTime))
```

But, that is not working, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-11-25T15:20:00' could not be parsed at index 19
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine the date and time strings to create a date-time string in ISO 8601 format which you can parse into `LocalDateTime` and then convert into `Instant` by using the applicable `ZoneId`. Note that the modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate = "2021-11-25";
        String strTime = "15:20";
        String strDateTime = strDate + "T" + strTime;
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        Instant instant = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-11-25T15:20:00Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/4H9Prv)

#### Some alternative approaches:

1. Create the instance of `LocalDateTime` can be as suggested by [daniu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2837741/daniu) i.e. parse the date and time strings individually and create the instance of `LocalDateTime` using them.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate = "2021-11-25";
        String strTime = "15:20";
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.parse(strDate), LocalTime.parse(strTime));
        Instant instant = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/MWOG0a)

2. Create the instance of `ZonedDateTime` using [`ZonedDateTime#of(LocalDate, LocalTime, ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.LocalTime-java.time.ZoneId-) as suggested by [Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v). Another variant that you can try with this approach is by using [`ZonedDateTime#of(LocalDateTime, ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of-java.time.LocalDateTime-java.time.ZoneId-).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate = "2021-11-25";
        String strTime = "15:20";
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.parse(strDate), LocalTime.parse(strTime),
                                                ZoneId.systemDefault());
        // Alternatively
        // ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.parse(strDate), LocalTime.parse(strTime)),
        //                                          ZoneId.systemDefault());
        
        Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/XjRVox)

3. Combine the date and time strings to create a date-time string in ISO 8601 format and parse the same to `ZonedDateTime` using `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate = "2021-11-25";
        String strTime = "15:20";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDate + "T" + strTime, dtf);
        Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/3wRBKd)

4. Create an instance of `LocalDateTime` by parsing the date and time strings, and use the [`LocalDateTime#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDateTime.html#toInstant-java.time.ZoneOffset-) to get the required `Instant`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate = "2021-11-25";
        String strTime = "15:20";
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.parse(strDate), LocalTime.parse(strTime));
        Instant instant = ldt.toInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(ldt));
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/7GrVDq)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Comment: Matter of taste, but I find it cleaner to parse each item individually into a `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` respectively, then combine them by `LocalDateTime.of()`. This way you get around having to juggle around with the intermediate string.

Comment: @daniu - This is indeed a great suggestion! Now, I have incorporated it into the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I’m with @daniu here. We may even combine directly into a `ZonedDateTime` using the three-arg `ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate, LocalTime, ZoneId)`.

Comment: Correct, @OleV.V. and I've written many answers in these ways . It's just that I wrote the first solution that came to my mind. I can still think of at least three more solutions but at the moment, I do not have time to write them . I will add them whenever I will time to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Your date string doesn't include a timezone, so it cannot be parsed directly to a `ZonedDateTime` (see javadoc for `ZonedDateTime#parse`).

Try parsing the string to a `LocalDateTime` instead (using `LocalDate#parse)`.

You can then convert the the `LocalDateTime`to an `Instant` using `LocalDateTime#toInstant` or to a `ZonedDateTime` using `LocalDateTime#atZone`

Comment: @Abra IMO my answer does indeed provide clear and sufficient information to solve the problem. Granted: it's not cut-and-paste ready, but then again the main purpose of this platform is helping people learn and understand, not providing readymade cut-and-paste solutions, right?

Comment: @marthursson actually my question is misleading I just need to convert string to an Instant, what is the simple way of doing that?

Comment: @Leff Updated answer with information on how to produce an Instant