# Can I instantiate a new Date already with a timezone in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, date

I need to generate a `new Date();` already with the correct time zone, because I need to record the date and time that a new data is received on my server. (I know that you can use the `SimpleDateFormat`, but it requires to parse a already created string).
I'm using **Java** + **Spring Boot**.

Comment: How does `new Date()` not work? Note that a Date has no timezone info, so what is your question? By the way, Date is practically deprecated in favour of using `LocalDate` and/or other java.time classes.

Comment: It's because ```new Date()``` uses the local machine time, but I'd want to create a new Date  with a specific timezone (for example, Brazil (UTC-3).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: No you cannot. A `Date` hasn’t got as in cannot have a time zone (I know that its `toString` method tries to fool you into thinking that it has got one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:** You can use `ZonedDateTime` with the applicable `ZoneId`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Use the applicable ZoneId
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Asia/Dubai");
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);
        System.out.println(now);
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
2021-10-30T02:26:07.471319+04:00[Asia/Dubai]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/rVB1MR)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

#### A note on `java.util.Date`:

A `java.util.Date` object simply represents an instant on the timeline — a wrapper around the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT). Since it does not hold any timezone information, its **[`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--)** function applies the JVM's timezone to return a `String` in the format, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`, derived from this ***milliseconds*** value. To get the `String` representation of the `java.util.Date` object in a different format and timezone, you need to use `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired format and the applicable timezone e.g.

```
Date date = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
String strDateNewYork = sdf.format(date);

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
String strDateUtc = sdf.format(date);
```

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use DateFormat. For example,

```
SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = isoFormat.parse("2010-05-23T09:01:02");
```