# How to get day of the week, day of month, month and year?

Tags: java, android, date, google-apps-script, calendar

The below code is to check the day of the week, now I want to check the date, month, year ...how to modify it?

```
import java.util.Calendar

ImageView imageView;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.setTime(now_date);

imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.IMAGE1);
} else if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.TUESDAY) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.IMAGE2);
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is NOT JAVA

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Also not all calendars have a 7 day week, so your code will not always work. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DayOfWeek`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). They always use the 7 day week known from the Gregorian calendar and related calendars.

Comment: This code build is successful but app not opening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time through desugaring

Consider using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. Let’s first see how checking the day of the week goes:

```
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    
    switch (today.getDayOfWeek()) {
    case MONDAY:
        System.out.println("Set image to Monday’s image here");
        break;

    case TUESDAY:
        System.out.println("Set image to Tuesday’s image here");
        break;

    default:
        throw new AssertionError("Unsupported day of week: " + today.getDayOfWeek());
    }
```

I trust you to fill out the remaining five days of the week yourself, and also to set the image resource of the image view as in your question. The way my code stands, when I ran it today, Monday November 1, the output was:

> Set image to Monday’s image here

It works because `getDayOfWeek()` returns an instance of the `DayOfWeek` enum and Java allows us to switch on enums.

For the day of the month:

```
    switch (today.getDayOfMonth()) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Set image to image for 1st day of month here");
        break;

    case 2:
        System.out.println("Set image to image for 2nd day of month here");
        break;

    default:
        throw new AssertionError("Unsupported day of month: " + today.getDayOfWeek());
    }
```

> Set image to image for 1st day of month here

Again fill out up to 31 yourself. While a day of week is an enum, a day of a month is a plain `int`.

The case of the month is similar to the day of the week in that there’s an enum that we prefer to use. `getMonth()` returns an instance of the `Month` enum, and in your `switch` statement you will have cases `JANUARY`, `FEBRUARY`, etc.

Finally `getYear()` again returns an `int`, so the year case will be similar to the day of the month with cases 2021, 2022, etc.

Edit: you asked:

> … can you give code to validate both date and month in single switch
> case? … only for one case its enough for "DATE" and "MONTH"...rest i
> will do it

If you’re comfortable with `switch` statements, you may also nest them inside each other:

```
    switch (today.getMonth()) {
    case JANUARY:
        switch (today.getDayOfMonth()) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Set image to image for 1st day of January here");
            break;

        // …

        default:
            throw new AssertionError("Unsupported day of January: " + today.getDayOfWeek());
        }
        break;

    // …
        
    default:
        throw new AssertionError("Unsupported month: " + today.getMonth());
    }
```

### Alternative: use maps

For a slightly advanced but also very elegant solution, instead of the longish `switch` or `if`-`else` statement define the images to use for each day of week in an `EnumMap<DayOfWeek, String>` (if the image reference in `R.drawable.IMAGE1` is a `String`, sorry, I don’t know Android so can’t tell). For the day of the month you may either use a `HashMap<Integer, String>` or an arrays of strings.

Edit: I think the map approaches becomes particularly appealing when it comes to combining month and day of month. I am using Java 9 syntax here and hope it works with desugaring, it’s not something I know:

```
private static final Map<MonthDay, String> IMAGES_PER_DAY
        = Map.ofEntries(
                Map.entry(MonthDay.of(Month.JANUARY, 1), "Image for Jan 1"),
                Map.entry(MonthDay.of(Month.JANUARY, 2), "Image for Jan 2"),
                // …
                Map.entry(MonthDay.of(Month.NOVEMBER, 1), "Image for Nov 1"),
                // …
                Map.entry(MonthDay.of(Month.DECEMBER, 31), "Image for Dec 31"));
```

Now picking the right image for today’s date is pretty simple:

```
    String imageReference = IMAGES_PER_DAY.get(MonthDay.from(today));
    System.out.println("Set image to " + imageReference);
```

> Set image to Image for Nov 1

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: Thankyou for your response, can you give code to validate both date and month in single switch case?

Comment: No , only for one  case its enough for "DATE" and "MONTH"...rest i will do it

Comment: Please see my two edits.

Answer (score 3):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:** Use `ZonedDateTime` with the applicable `ZoneId` and retrieve the required values from it.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Specify the applicable ZoneId e.g.
        // ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"))
        // to get the current date-time in that timezone
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();

        DayOfWeek dow = now.getDayOfWeek();
        System.out.println(dow);

        int weekDayNum = dow.getValue();
        System.out.println(weekDayNum);

        String weekDayName = dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(weekDayName);

        int year = now.getYear();
        System.out.println(year);

        Month month = now.getMonth();
        System.out.println(month);

        int monthValue = month.getValue();
        System.out.println(monthValue);

        int dayOfMonth = now.getDayOfMonth();
        System.out.println(dayOfMonth);

        int dayOfYear = now.getDayOfYear();
        System.out.println(dayOfYear);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
MONDAY
1
Monday
2021
NOVEMBER
11
1
305
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/5BLBCu)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Similar to DAY_OF_WEEK, you can get other fields from Calendar instance.

Please check Java Docs for more details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Cool, will keep in might next time.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the documentation
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html
you can get the week, month and year in this way

```
Date today = new Date(); 
cal.setTime(today); 
int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 
int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int dayOfYear = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: I new to java ,so please specify the condition to verify the Date,month and year if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY)