# Parsing LocalDateTime with day-of-year and differing number of subsecond digits

Tags: java, parsing, time

I have data using year and **day-of-year** (1-365/366) plus a time-of-day, such as `2018-338T14:02:57.47583`, rather than year-month-day.

I am trying to write a function where I input a timestamp, it runs it through a bunch of regexes, and returns a pattern that I can use to parse that timestamp via LocalDateTime.parse.  I have a function that does this except with one issue.

```java
public static String getInputFormat(String rawFirst) {
            
    String first = rawFirst.replaceAll("[^-.:/ a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
    
    ImmutableMap<String, String> regexFormatMap = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, String>()
            .put("(-)?[0-9]{4}(Z?)", "YYYY")
            .put("(-)?[0-9]{4}-((00[1-9])|(0[1-9][0-9])|([1-2][0-9][0-9])|(3(([0-5][0-9])|(6[0-6]))))(T)(([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-3])):[0-5][0-9](Z?)", "yyyy-DDD'T'HH:mm")
            .put("(-)?[0-9]{4}-((00[1-9])|(0[1-9][0-9])|([1-2][0-9][0-9])|(3(([0-5][0-9])|(6[0-6]))))(T)(([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-3])):[0-5][0-9]:(([0-5][0-9])|60)(\\.([0-9]{1,6}))?(Z?)", "yyyy-DDD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSS")
            .put("(-)?[0-9]{4}-((00[1-9])|(0[1-9][0-9])|([1-2][0-9][0-9])|(3(([0-5][0-9])|(6[0-6]))))(T)(([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-4]))(Z?)", "yyyy-DDD'T'HH")
            .put("(-)?[0-9]{4}-((00[1-9])|(0[1-9][0-9])|([1-2][0-9][0-9])|(3(([0-5][0-9])|(6[0-6]))))(T)24((:00)|(:00:00))?(Z?)", "yyyy-DDD'T'HH:mm:ss")
            .put("(-)?[0-9]{4}-((00[1-9])|(0[1-9][0-9])|([1-2][0-9][0-9])|(3(([0-5][0-9])|(6[0-6]))))(T)24:00:00(\\.([0]{1,6}))(Z?)", "yyyy-DDD'T'HH:mm:ss")
            .put("(-)?[0-9]{4}-((00[1-9])|(0[1-9][0-9])|([1-2][0-9][0-9])|(3(([0-5][0-9])|(6[0-6]))))(Z?)", "yyyy-DDD")
            .build();
            
    for (String regex : regexFormatMap.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(first.matches(regex) + ": " + first + " fits " + regex);
        if (first.matches(regex)) {
            System.out.println("Returning pattern " + regexFormatMap.get(regex));
            return regexFormatMap.get(regex);
        }
    }
            
    System.out.println("did not match pattern, returning default pattern used with test data, eventually this should just fail.");
    return "yyyy-DDD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSS";
}
```

I can't figure out how to handle an arbitrary number of subsecond digits, i.e.,

- `"2018-338T14:02:57.47583"`
- `"2018-338T14:02:57.475835"`
- `"2018-338T14:02:57.4758352"`
- `"2018-338T14:02:57.47583529"`

etc.

I want to do this in as general a way as possible, so ideally I wouldn't be checking for each possibility.

One solution would be to have the output format string have nine subsecond digits, and then pad the input string, but the problem is it's getting quite clunky to check whether I should pad it and by how much.  I want this to handle a wide variety of strings, and to be expandable just by adding more entries to the regex map instead of adding complexity and special cases elsewhere.

Maybe I can't get everything I want here, but I'd love a solution if you can think of one.  Thanks!

Comment: I just wanted to note, that here the new java time classes are superior to the old situation where one had only microseconds, and not second decimals. The errors that 12 or 12345678 microseconds can cause...

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()` in order to build a flexible `DateTimeFormatter` which parses `String`s with variable fractions of second, using the method [`appendFraction(TemporalField, int, int, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendFraction-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-int-int-boolean-).

For instance like this, where I used 5 nanos of second up to 8 (which might not be the best idea, but it handles all your example `String`s):

```java
DateTimeFormatter ldtVarFracSecFormatter =
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("uuuu-DDD'T'HH:mm:ss")
                .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 5, 8, true)
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Here's an example using the `String`s from your question:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String a = "2018-338T14:02:57.47583";
    String b = "2018-338T14:02:57.475835"; 
    String c = "2018-338T14:02:57.4758352"; 
    String d = "2018-338T14:02:57.47583529";
    
    DateTimeFormatter ldtVarFracSecFormatter = 
            new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                    .appendPattern("uuuu-DDD'T'HH:mm:ss")
                    .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 5, 8, true)
                    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    
    LocalDateTime aLdt = LocalDateTime.parse(a, ldtVarFracSecFormatter);
    LocalDateTime bLdt = LocalDateTime.parse(b, ldtVarFracSecFormatter);
    LocalDateTime cLdt = LocalDateTime.parse(c, ldtVarFracSecFormatter);
    LocalDateTime dLdt = LocalDateTime.parse(d, ldtVarFracSecFormatter);

    System.out.println(aLdt);
    System.out.println(bLdt);
    System.out.println(cLdt);           
    System.out.println(dLdt);
}
```

The output is (implicitly using `LocalDateTime.toString()`):

```
2018-12-04T14:02:57.475830
2018-12-04T14:02:57.475835
2018-12-04T14:02:57.475835200
2018-12-04T14:02:57.475835290
```

Comment: Good solution! Just added an important missing part, `Locale`.

Comment: Thanks, @ArvindKumarAvinash, I left the locale here on purpose because there is nothing locale-based in the Strings, but one may assume it's always better to specify a locale.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a complex and error-prone RegEx solution for this requirement, you can use `u-D'T'H:m:s[.[SSSSSSSSS][SSSSSSSS][SSSSSSS][SSSSSS][SSSSS][SSSS][SSS][SS][S]]` as the pattern with `DateTimeFormatter` which allows the optional patterns to be specified within square brackets.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                "u-D'T'H:m:s[.[SSSSSSSSS][SSSSSSSS][SSSSSSS][SSSSSS][SSSSS][SSSS][SSS][SS][S]]", Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        // Test
        Stream.of(
                "2018-338T14:02:57.47583", 
                "2018-338T14:02:57.475835", 
                "2018-338T14:02:57.4758352",
                "2018-338T14:02:57.47583529"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(s, dtf)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2018-12-04T14:02:57.475830
2018-12-04T14:02:57.475835
2018-12-04T14:02:57.475835200
2018-12-04T14:02:57.475835290
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Xqb0rP)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Comment: Clever use of streams to demonstrate parsing. I’ll be using that.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure what your real goal is. If the point is parsing those strings, don’t use any pattern. Build your formatter from formatters that are already built-in:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ORDINAL_DATE)
        .appendLiteral('T')
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
        .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);
```

This parses all of your example strings:

```
    String[] timestampStrings = {
            "2018-338T14:02:57.47583",
            "2018-338T14:02:57.475835",
            "2018-338T14:02:57.4758352",
            "2018-338T14:02:57.47583529"
    };
    
    for (String tss : timestampStrings) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(tss, PARSER);
        System.out.format("%-26s -> %s%n", tss, ldt);
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> 2018-338T14:02:57.47583    -> 2018-12-04T14:02:57.475830
> 2018-338T14:02:57.475835   -> 2018-12-04T14:02:57.475835
> 2018-338T14:02:57.4758352  -> 2018-12-04T14:02:57.475835200
> 2018-338T14:02:57.47583529 -> 2018-12-04T14:02:57.475835290
> ```

Don’t be confused by the fact that `LocalDateTIme.toString()` always prints groups at 3 decimals (if any decimals on the seconds at all), filling with trailing zeroes as necessary. The numbers, the times printed do agree with your strings.

The ISO 8601 format for an ordinal date, like `2018-338` for the 338th day of year 2018, is not often used, but java.time includes a formatter for it. The commonly used `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME` accepts from 0 through 9 digits of decimals on the seconds, a range which is more than wide enough to accommodate all of your timestamp strings.

If for some reason that I have not yet understood you do want a pattern, the answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash gives you one.

Obviously like everyone else here I am using and recommending java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.