# How to get day of the week of GMT using kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, datetime, utc, dayofweek, gmt

For EXAMPLE, current UTC time is:

17:14:24 UTC
Friday, 5 November 2021

I want to get the result "6" (Sunday = 1 => Friday = 6)

Comment: What platforms are you targeting? Java? Native? Multiplatform?

Comment: What makes you want to use a *number* for the day of the week? If Kotlin has got enums, use one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`kotlinx.datetime`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime) (which is multiplatform):

```
import kotlinx.datetime.DayOfWeek
import kotlinx.datetime.Instant
import kotlinx.datetime.TimeZone
import kotlinx.datetime.isoDayNumber
import kotlinx.datetime.toLocalDateTime

public val DayOfWeek.dayNumberStartingFromSunday: Int
    get() = when (this) {
        DayOfWeek.SUNDAY -> 1
        else -> isoDayNumber + 1
    }

fun main() {
//    val now: Instant = Clock.System.now()
    val now = Instant.parse("2021-11-05T17:14:24Z")
    val datetimeInUtc = now.toLocalDateTime(TimeZone.UTC)
    val dayNumberStartingFromSunday = datetimeInUtc.dayOfWeek.dayNumberStartingFromSunday
    println(dayNumberStartingFromSunday) // 6
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first day of the week is `Locale` specific. Since you want the first day of the week to be `Sunday`, you can use `Locale.US`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getDayOfWeekValue(LocalDateTime.of(2021, 11, 5, 17, 14, 24)));
    }

    static int getDayOfWeekValue(LocalDateTime input) {
        return Math.toIntExact(
                ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
                        input.with(
                                TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(
                                        WeekFields.of(Locale.US)
                                            .getFirstDayOfWeek())), 
                        input.plusDays(1))); 
        // Note: One day has been added as ChronoUnit.DAYS.between excludes
        // the second parameter while calculating the number of days
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
6
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/LYMNNz)

**Note**: Test this code with `Locale.UK` (for which the first day of the week is Monday) and you will get 5 as the output. As per your requirement, you can change the definition of the function like

```
static int getDayOfWeekValue(LocalDateTime input, Locale locale) {
    return Math.toIntExact(
            ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
                    input.with(
                            TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(
                                    WeekFields.of(locale)
                                        .getFirstDayOfWeek())), 
                    input.plusDays(1))); 
    // Note: One day has been added as ChronoUnit.DAYS.between excludes
    // the second parameter while calculating the number of days
}
```

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.</sup>