# Mapping Error: oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP to java.util.Date while using Apache Camel

Tags: java, oracle, apache-camel, date-conversion, sql-timestamp

I am using Apache Camel framework of java in which I am fetching the data from oracle db with a column of type `timestamp`. When I am trying to map this to variable of type `java.util.Date`, it is throwing the following error mentioned.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Could not find a suitable setter for property lastupdated as there isn't a setter method with same type oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP nor type conversion possible: 
No type converter available to convert from type oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP to the required type java.util.Date with value "2022-11-16 19:04:27.067"
```

Can anyone help me with this?

I tried to use the following datatypes of java-

1. `java.util.Date`
2. `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP`
3. `java.sql.Timestamp`

But still the error is same.

Comment: Use `LocalDateTime`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

create a camel convertor and add it camel context annotation can be change for  spring + camel or quarkus + camel it is basic camel annotation

```
@Converter(generateLoader = true)
public class DateConvertor {
    @Converter
    public static java.sql.Timestamp toTimeStamp(oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP timestamp) {
        return timestamp.timestampValue()
    }
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: I think you can't add camel contex properly what is your stack spring + camel ?