# Storing ZonedDateTime in Postgres in UTC

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, timestamp-with-timezone, zoneddatetime

I receive a variable as `ZonedDateTime` in UTC and I want to persist in a Postgres column in UTC. The column currently is type of `timestamptz` and I want to read is back in the same `ZonedDateTime` format. No conversion is between.

Reading it back converts to my local time zone which I don't want. My question is, is the `ZonedDateTime` to `timestamptz` correct?

Comment: `timestamptz` does not store the timezone or offset. It just stores the value as UTC time. Read [Datetimes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html): Section *8.5.1.3. Time Stamps* for the complete explanation.

Comment: So it fits my purpose as what I receive is always UTC.

Comment: I would highly recommend you read the section I mentioned, if you have not already. As you have found the value you get back may not be at UTC.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

Comment: `ZonedDateTime` isn’t really the right type for a date and time in UTC. If you can change it, prefer `OffsetDateTime` as more correct and less heavy-weight.

Comment: [TimezoneStorageType – Hibernate’s improved timezone mapping](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-6-offsetdatetime-and-zoneddatetime/)

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Writing:

```java
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myZonedDateTime.toOffsetDateTime() )
```

Retrieving:

```java
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class )
```

You cannot get back a `ZonedDateTime` object, as moments with a time zone are *not* supported as a data type in Postgres nor in the SQL standard.

## Details

### The SQL standard

The SQL standard barely mentions some date-time types, without defining much in the way of details and behavior. So databases vary greatly in their approach to date-time handling.

The SQL standard does define the types `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. But those are misnomers, were the standard. authors meant offset-from-UTC, not actual time zones.

### JDBC mapping

So the JDBC standard maps `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` values to the [`java.time.OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) type. That type represents a moment as seen with an offset from UTC of some number of hours-minutes-seconds, positive (eastward) or negative (westward).

JDBC does *not* address either of the `java.time.Instant` nor [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) classes.

### Convert `ZonedDateTime` to `OffsetDateTime`

> I receive a variable as ZonedDateTime in UTC and I want to persist in a Postgres column in UTC.

[Convert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toOffsetDateTime()) your `ZonedDateTime` to an `OffsetDateTime`.

```java
OffsetDateTime odt = myZdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;
```

For example, a date-time this year with `Europe/Paris` zone assigned will convert to a date-time with an offset of `+01:00` or `+02:00`.

### Writing/retrieving in database

The particular offset within your `OffsetDateTime` object does not matter. When saved to a Postgres column of the type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, any supplied offset or zone information is used to adjust the value to an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. This adjustment is a Postgres-specific behavior, not specified in the standard. Some other databases do the same, some do not.

Send to database.

```java
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```java
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

You cannot get back your `ZonedDateTime` object directly. As discussed above, neither Postgres nor the SQL standard store date-times with a time zone.

If the original time zone is important to you, you must store that separately in another textual column.

```java
myPreparedStatement.setString( … , zdt.getZone().toString() ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```java
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( myResultSet.getString( … ) ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( zoneId ) ;
```

By the way, be aware that time zone names do change on occasion.

### Always UTC

Postgres *always* stores a date-time value in a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column with an offset of zero.

JDBC always retrieves a value from a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column as a `OffsetDateTime` object with an offset of zero.

⚠️ Unfortunately, some **tooling, middleware, and frameworks choose to inject a default time zone or offset**. Between the database and you, the retrieved UTC value may be adjusted. This does *not* happen with straight JDBC. But beware of frameworks built on top of JDBC; these may choose to inject an offset or zone. While well-intentioned, this anti-feature does cause much confusion.

### Use full type names

I suggest you not use the abbreviation `timestampz`.

For one thing, that term is proprietary to Postgres, not standard.

And for another thing, that term is too easily misread as `timestamp`. Given how crucial it is to correctly choose `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` versus `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, I suggest always spelling them out the long way.