# Why Instant is not converted from UTC to timezone of PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, java-time

On my PostgreSQL, if I run the script:

```
show timezone;
```

it returns

```
Europe/Rome
```

so according to this, I have configured

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: Europe/Rome
```

I have a table TestPostgre with a column **datetime_using_instant** of **timestamp** data type.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_postgre")
public class TestPostgre {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "pk", nullable = false)
    private String pk;
    
    @Column(name = "datetime_using_instant", nullable = false)
    private Instant dateTimeUsingInstant;
    
}
```

Using JpaRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface TestPostgreRepository extends JpaRepository<TestPostgre, String> {
    
}
```

when saving a TestPostgre instance with dateTimeUsingInstant value of 2023-10-11T12:30:00Z, on PostgreSQL the value is still 2023-10-11 12:30:00.000, but between UTC and Europe/Rome there are 2 hours of offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PostgreSQL Time Stamps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT-TIME-STAMPS)

In a literal that has been determined to be **timestamp without time zone**, **PostgreSQL will silently ignore any time zone indication**. That is, the **resulting value** is derived from the date/time fields in the input value, and **is not adjusted for time zone**.

A nice tutorial for the difference between timestamp (TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE) and timestampz (TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) with examples can be found at [postgresqltutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-timestamp/)

Answer (score 1):

[`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is an instantaneous point on the timeline. It is independent of a time zone and always provides a moment in UTC i.e. with a time zone offset of "+00:00", typically displayed as `Z` (stands for Zulu).

The recommended practice is to keep the value of `jdbc.time_zone` as `UTC`

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

There is a good tutorial [here](https://www.baeldung.com/mysql-jdbc-timezone-spring-boot) and here is what the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) says:

> For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in
> UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean
> Time, GMT).

You can always convert an `Instant` into other types e.g. `ZonedDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime` etc. for display purposes e.g.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome"));
System.out.println(instant);
System.out.println(zdt);
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
2023-10-12T11:18:44.036798Z
2023-10-12T13:18:44.036798+02:00[Europe/Rome]
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/e65zuA)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sub>Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.</sub>

Comment: jdbc.time_zone property must match with database timezone?

Comment: @PaulMarcelinBejan definitely not, the feature was introduced in [HHH-10399](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10399), which clearly states that should be DB timezone.